# Fluent Validation: Use another validator when a validator fails

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

Currently, I have a property that needs to be either foo or bar depending on user input but not anything else. I have a validator that does something like this:

```
When(x => !(x.MyProperty.Length >= 11 && x.MyProperty.Length <= 25), () =>
{
    RuleFor(x => x.MyProperty).SetValidator(new BarValidator());
});
```

The rules inside the When are more complicated than the example above, and they are the rules for Foo.

I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
when FooValidator fails
     check BarValidator
```

Is this possible using Fluent Validation?